link extraction using xpath and beautifulsoup not working
I want to extract link which is nested as /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/a in xpath , also see detailed nesting image
if helpful, these div have some class also.
I tried
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.visionias.in/resources/daily_current_affairs_programs.php?type=1&m=05&y=2024')

soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)

element = soup.find_element_by_xpath("./html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/a")
href = element.get_attribute('href')
print(href)

this code gave error
 line 9, in <module>
    element = soup.find_element_by_xpath("./html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/a")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

and also tried other method
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.visionias.in/resources/daily_current_affairs_programs.php?type=1&m=05&y=2024')

soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)

href = soup('a')('div')[1]('div')[2]('div')[1]('div')[0]('div')[0]('div')[0]('div')[0]('div')[0][href]
#href = element.get_attribute('href')
print(href)

this gave error
    href = soup('a')('div')[1]('div')[2]('div')[1]('div')[0]('div')[0]('div')[0]('div')[0]('div')[0][href]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable


expected outcome should be : https://www.visionias.in/resources/material/?id=3731&type=daily_current_affairs or material/?id=3731&type=daily_current_affairs

Also some other links have same kind of nesting as above, is there any way to filter the links using the text inside/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/p, for example text here is 18 may 2024, this p tag has an id also but it is not consisent or doesnt have a pattern, so not quite usuable to me.
I have seen other answers on stackoverflow but that isn't working for me
Also if possible please elaborate the answer, as I have to apply same code to some other sites as well.

Your XPATHs are fragile to the extreme, to be nice about it. Please state clearly what information are you after, from that page. What url are you after? today? yesterday?

As of now I want today's url, but there could be change in requirement sometimes.

Refer the selenium code below to extract all links and print it to console:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.visionias.in/resources/daily_current_affairs_programs.php?type=1&m=05&y=2024")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='center']//a")))

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))

Console output:
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3731&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3729&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3727&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3723&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3717&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3715&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3705&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3703&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3701&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3699&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3690&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3688&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3687&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3684&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3682&type=daily_current_affairs
https://www.visionias.in/resources/material?id=3676&type=daily_current_affairs

Process finished with exit code 0

SUGGESTION: I highly recommend you to read about absolute and relative XPaths. And the advantages of using relative over absolute XPaths. Few links below for your reference:

What is the difference between absolute and relative xpaths? Which is preferred in Selenium automation testing?
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-relative-and-absolute-xpath-in-selenium

UPDATE: Use the below code if you want to extract the link based on the specific date.
link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(),'18 May 2024')]//following::a[1]")))
print(link.get_attribute("href"))


Thanks for getting back to me, and I will definitely read the difference between both.

Apologies for not marking the answer as accepted. I was testing the code, and expecting some more answers. But your code is not returning what I need, For extracting all the links and its text from a webpage I have some code in beautifulsoup , what I could not figure out is how to extract specific links filtered according to the date( or the text inside the p tag).

It is working as expected. Thanks a lot. + I have not attained 15 reputation so my like is not being marked but has been recorded and I have marked the answer as accepted.

Since "18 May 2024" is constant and needs to be updated manually, I alloted a variable for it and placed it instead of "18 May 2024" and made no changes, but the extracted href is only of the latest link no matter what date it is. What should i further do?  CHANGES  I DID : d2 = today.strftime("%d %B %Y")     link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(),d2)]//following::a[1]"))) 

You can try this XPath, By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='center']//a)[1]". The last digit [1] locates the first occurrence of the element which is 19 & 20 May 2024. If you want to locate 18 May 2024, just change it to [2] and so on.
